# db2 force application that connected before today

Tags: database, db2, connection, db2-luw

Good day,

I am trying to find from Google is there any db2 command to release connection that connected before today, but I cant get a correct result.

Normally when we want to release some specific connection from a database, we will use command as follow:

```
db2 force application (17842)
```

Where the 17842 is the application Handle Id If I am not wrong.

Or we use following command to release all connection to the database:

```
db2 QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS
```

Now, I am thinking, is there any command that can allow me to release connection that connected before today? So that I can release them but still keep the connection that connected since today.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL you can find the start time of a connection:

```
select application_handle, connection_start_time
from table(mon_get_connection(cast(NULL as bigint), -2)) as t
```

To filter for connections older than a day:

```
select application_handle, connection_start_time
from table(mon_get_connection(cast(NULL as bigint), -2)) as t
where (current timestamp - 1 day) > connection_start_time
```

You could use that as input to `force application` and invoke it using the [ADMIN_CMD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023574.html).